# Python new data to a class in a running in a thread

Tags: python

So im trying to understand threading - and thought I start with something like this:

A class or part of it running in a thread - and giving it new data to work with every now and then, here its just printing.

However its not really updating the data it seems... Actually - it seems like its stuck after the threading starts and doesnt do anything else?

here is what I tried out:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def printnum(self):
        print("Num is: " + str(self.num))

    def printloop(self):
        while True:
            print(self.num)
            time.sleep(1)

    def setnum(self, num):
        self.num = num


test = Test(123)
test.printnum() 
time.sleep(2)

test.setnum(123456)
test.printnum() 
time.sleep(2)

threading.Thread(target=test.printloop()).start()

time.sleep(5)
test.setnum(31245)
test.printnum() 


time.sleep(5)
test1.setcount(532556663)
test.printnum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `threading.Thread` constructor you're *calling* the `printloop` method.  You need to pass it in without calling it, so remove the parentheses:

```
threading.Thread(target=test.printloop()).start()
                                      ~~ <-- remove these
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! Now I can play around more

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this to:

```
Threading.Thread(printloop).start()
```

ie change it from printloop() to printloop.  This passes the function as an object for the Thread to execute.  Currently you are evaluation printloop() and the Thread() method expects printloop() to return a new function for it!

Furthermore, you may to run into major difficulties when you pass data to the new Thread - you may need to put locks in to ensure messages are not lost / corrupted. Check out this tutorial on how to do so (Synchronising Threads):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm